# No Internet connection on VM

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, internet, hyper-v

I can't seem to connect to the internet on my VM which is running Windows 8. I followed most of the instructions that I've found on Google or YouTube but it didn't seem to help. I can have a wired or wireless connection.

This shows up on the VM when I diagnose it and I don't know how to fix it:

[image: 1]

Anyone that can help is appreciated.

I am using Hyper-V Manager for the VMs. As for the configuration I made a new Virtual switch -> External -> Chose my wireless adapter and ticked "Allow management OS to share this adapter".

Comment: Which VM software are you using and what's the VM's network configuration set to?

Answer (score 0):

You’re using a wireless adapter for bridging. This is unlikely to work, because a wireless access point (or router) expects exactly one network interface on the other end of a wireless link. If you’re bridging, your VMs’ network interfaces will appears side by side with your real network connection. Again: This is not supported. See [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode#bridged_client_mode_issues) for a (very good!) in-depth explanation.

You could use Internet Connection Sharing in combination with a host-only network on Hyper-V. That way your PC will act as a router for your VMs and they’ll be hidden.